# Spotify API token request - 400 `SyntaxError: Unexpected End of Input`

Tags: reactjs, fetch, spotify, next.js

I'm working on a `Next.js` web app that needs to connect with the Spotify API. I successfully got the `authorization_code`, but I am getting a 400 error on the `api/token` endpoint.

I have already tried replacing `body` with `params` and `data` in the fetch call. I have also tried parsing the JSON into a `const` before passing it to fetch.

```
try {
    const res = await fetch('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            Authorization: `Basic ${process.env.SPOTIFY_CREDS_BASE_SIXTYFOUR}`,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            grant_type: 'authorization_code',
            code: authCode,
            redirect_uri: process.env.SPOTIFY_REDIRECT_URI,
            client_id: process.env.SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID,
            client_secret: process.env.SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET,
        }),
    });
    const data = await res.json();

    dispatch({ type: GET_NEW_ACCESS_TOKEN_SUCCESS });
} catch (error) {
    console.error('getNewTokens() ERROR', error);
    dispatch({ type: GET_NEW_ACCESS_TOKEN_FAILURE });
}
```

I expect to receive the access tokens, but instead I am seeing:

```
VM538:1 POST https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token 400 (Bad Request)
```

and

```
getNewTokens() ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at _callee$ (AuthActions.js:37)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js:45)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js:271)
    at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as next] (runtime.js:97)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:5)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:27)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to successfully complete the request using the `fetch` library, but using the `request` library with the same headers worked successfully.

```
    var authOptions = {
        url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
        form: {
            code: code,
            redirect_uri: SPOTIFY_REDIRECT_URI,
            grant_type: 'authorization_code',
            client_id: SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID,
            client_secret: SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET,
        },
        json: true
    };

    request.post(authOptions, (error, response, body) => {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            // Success
        } else {
            // Failure
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try update your header like below, as you are passing JSON on your body

```
headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; application/json', 
         Authorization: `Basic ${process.env.SPOTIFY_CREDS_BASE_SIXTYFOUR}`,
    }
```

Updated your header to accept JSON format also

I tried to update your request and further updating this header am able to post my body as expected. As i don't have credentials i am receiving 500, but my request reached server.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! Unfortunately this solution did not seem to work for me. The API docs specify that `Content-Type` header must be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Anything else is giving a 415 incorrect media type error.

Comment: If yo change the content-type as suggested you are receiving 415? Pls fonfirm?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be due to JSON.stringify. please try content type application/json

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly! This could be the case, but the Spotify API docs specify that Content-Type header must be application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Anything else is giving a 415 incorrect media type error.

Comment: I have also tried using the `querystring.stringify()` method which encodes URI components to no avail.